# How many words does 지겹다 require?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

It seems 지겹다 is a 두 자리 서술어:

> 나는 여캐가 지겹다.
> I'm bored of female characters.

If 지겹다 is a 두 자리 서술어 in this context, it will mean 여캐가 is the 보어. But I've once been taught that the only words that require a 보어 are 되다(become) and 아니다(be not). So it's confusing. So how many words does 지겹다 require?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we do not count postpositions, one word is required. 지겹다 can be used as follows:

- **이 일은** 지겹다. (This work is boring.)
- 나는 **이 일이** 지겹다. (I am bored with this work.)

The first example sentence clearly shows that it needs only one word. For the second one that closely relates to your example, 나는 is the subject of the whole sentence; 이 일이 is the subject of the **predicate clause (서술절)** 이 일이 지겹다. Such a construction (called "a double subject construction") can also be found for other adjectives like 좋다 ("나는 네가 좋아."), 싫다 ("철수가 아이스크림이 싫대."), 즐겁다 ("너는 하루하루가 즐거워?"), 넓다 ("그 나라는 땅이 넓어."), etc.

Regarding the double subject constructions, [some Koreans might agree with you](https://www.dbpia.co.kr/Journal/articleDetail?nodeId=NODE07262785); however, the standard dictionary says:

> 보어(補語): 주어와 서술어만으로는 뜻이 완전하지 못한 문장에서, 그 불완전한 곳을 보충하여 뜻을 완전하게 하는 수식어. 국어에서는 **‘되다’, ‘아니다’** 앞에 조사 ‘이’, ‘가’를 취하여 나타나는 문장 성분을 말한다. ‘철수가 지도자가 되었다’의 ‘지도자가’ 따위이다.

In addition, it is *incorrect* to say that in the first example, the complement is 이 일은; what is the subject then? Therefore, the word required for 지겹다 is *not* 보어 *but* 주어.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a short form. More verbal then written. So less strict grammar.

It could be written more formally as below:

나는 여캐가 지겨워졌다.

나는 여캐 플레이가 지겹다. / 나는 여캐를 보는 것이 지겹다. / 나는 여캐를 그리는 것이 지겹다.

All of them could be said as "나는 여캐가 지겹다" in verbal communication.